# ssh to another server with different username

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, expect

I have to write a shell script which ssh to another server with other username without actually asking for a password from the user?
Due to constraints I cannot use key based authentication.
let,
Source Server -- abc.efg.com
Source UserName -- tom
Source Password -- tom123

Destination Server -- xyz.efc.com
Destination UserName -- bob
destination Password -- bob123

I have to place the bash script in source server.
Please let me know if something could be done using expect tool and/or sshpass.

It is okay for me to hardcode the password for destination server in the bash script but I cannot bear an interactive session, simply when I run he script, I want to see the destination server logged in with another username.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use key-authentication http://ornellas.apanela.com/dokuwiki/pub:ssh_key_auth

1. Generate your keys **`ssh-keygen`**
2. Copy the keys to your new box **`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub me@otherhost.com`**
3. ssh to other host without password **`ssh me@otherhost.com`**

Comment: He said: 'Due to constraints I cannot use key based authentication'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use expect to wrap ssh, but it's pretty hectic, and fails easily when there are network errors, so test it well or use a script specifically designed for wrapping ssh passwords.  Key based authentication is better.

You can prevent interactive sessions by redirecting standard input from the null device, ie.

```
ssh me@destination destination-command < /dev/null
```

About placing the script in the source server, if the script you are running is local, rather than remote, then you can pass the script on standard input, rather than the command line:

```
cat bashscript.sh | ssh me@destination
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install the `sshpass` program, which lets you write a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p bob123 ssh UserName@xyz.efc.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't as OpenSSH actively prevent headless password-based authentication. Use key-based authentication.

You may be able to fork the OpenSSH client code and patch it, but I think that is a bit excessive.

Comment: Can you tell me the script with key based authentication.